# R - Como somar valores com uma condição

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

Bom dia !

Tenho o DF abaixo, preciso somar os valores das contas (colunas com números) do SEMESTRE 1 com o 2 (caso tenha), por CNPJ e ANO. Assim, terei os valores totais do ANO emitido pelo CNPJ.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando usar o tidyverse para agrupar os valores, mas acho que estou usando a lógica errada e não esta dando certo.

Desde já, obrigado.

Obs: São 156 colunas de contas (essas que só tem números).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era bem simples

Consegui resolver utilizando a função

> aggregate()

Ficou:

```
Balancete <- aggregate(Balanceteo,                                                  
by = list(Balancete$CNPJ, Balancete$ANO),                                                  
FUN = sum)
```